# 1C 8.3. Как с помощью V83.COMConnector передать данные?

Tags: 1с

С помощью V83.COMConnector получаю данные с другой конфигурации:

```
Функция ПолучитьПодключениеКФайловойБД()
Параметры = "File=""Путь"";Usr=""Логин"";Pwd=""Пароль""";
V83COMConnector= Новый COMОбъект("V83.COMConnector");
Попытка
Возврат V83COMConnector.Connect(Параметры);
Исключение
Предупреждение ("Ошибка подключения!");
Возврат Неопределено;
КонецПопытки;
КонецФункции

Процедура КнопкаВыполнитьНажатие(Кнопка)

Соединение = ПолучитьПодключениеКФайловойБД();  
    
ЗапросБПЗО = Соединение.NewObject("Запрос");
ЗапросБПЗО.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ первые 15
|   ДокументЗаказПокупателя.Номер КАК Номер
|ИЗ
|   Документ.ЗаказПокупателя КАК ДокументЗаказПокупателя";
Выборка = ЗапросБПЗО.Выполнить().выбрать(); 
Пока Выборка.следующий() цикл
    Сообщить(Выборка.Номер);
КонецЦикла; 
        
КонецПроцедуры
```

А как передать данные с одной конфигурации в другую?

Например, если данные какой-нибудь Розницы передать в Бухгалтерию предприятия (т.е. не получаем, а передаем данные).

Если с `V83.COMConnector` не получится передать данные, то что можно применять для этого?

Comment: Через Com соединение можно полноценно работать на запись и чтение. Приведите пример, что именно вы хотите передать?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас создается объект Запрос с которым далее работаете;

```
ЗапросБПЗО = Соединение.NewObject("Запрос");
```

Если необходимо записать данные, создайте таким же образом соответствующий объект (Документ/Справочник) либо получите из запроса, и работайте с ним;

```
Док = ЗапросБПЗО.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();  // Получаем Док из Запроса
// Делаем что нужно
Док.Комментарий = "Исправление";
Док.Записать();  // Предусматриваем перепроведение документа если нужно !
```